# Mac mini does not boot

Tags: startup, mac-mini

I have an old Mac Mini 2011. It used to work perfectly fine. However, when I turned it off for a couple of hours, it stopped to boot. Only fans are working hard when I switch it on. Screen is black, does not reach the Apple logo, also, a keyboard does not respond - caps button is always off.

Comment: If fan spin is all you have, then try an [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). It’s possible that memory could be bad, but experience tells me your logic board died.  However Cost in time, labor, and parts, you’re probably better off getting a new(er) one than repairing this one.

Comment: Thanks, @Allan, I've tried SMC Reset, unfortunately, it didn't help. Looks like it's time to say good buy to an old friend.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  They’re good little machines, but unfortunately they do break.  If you’ve got some disassembly skills, you may be able to part it out on eBay for more than you’d get if you sell it as a whole unit.  Either way, at least you can recoup some money from it to put towards a replacement.